# drawing a circle around an tracked obejct, displaying it's radius and getting the pixels properies along the radius

Tags: python, html, css, windows, simplecv

I am really new to programming and I am currently trying to work with SimpleCV using Python 2.7 on a Windows 7. 
I am using a laser beam, pointing it directly on the ccd chip of a USB camera connected to the computer and getting a live video of the intensity of the light irradiation which just looks like a bright spot on the screen. What I need the programm to do is to tell me the  radius of the spot and the pixel properties meaning the color of each pixel along the radius, so that I can see how the light intensity declines (going from the center to the rim), in order to draw a gaussian distribution curve with that Information taking the highest light intensity as peak.

So for that I am using an already written code for tracking a white ball. So what it does is finding circular white blobs and drawing a circle around it. 
This works well for me so far besides the fact that it does not cirlce the whole lightspot but only the brightest spot in the center.
Now I would love to get the radius somehow displayed in form of numbers on the screen, and the properties of the pixels starting in the center and going farther out.
Since I am new to programming (as I already said), I don't even know where to start. I am hoping you guys can help me out! Thank you in advance!

This is the code I am using so far:

```
print __doc__

import SimpleCV

display = SimpleCV.Display()
cam = SimpleCV.Camera()
normaldisplay = True

while display.isNotDone():
    if display.mouseRight:
        normaldisplay = not(normaldisplay)
        print "Display Mode:"

img = cam.getImage().flipHorizontal()
dist = img.colorDistance(SimpleCV.Color.BLACK)
segmented = dist.stretch(200,255)
blobs = segmented.findBlobs()
if blobs:
    circles = blobs.filter([b.isCircle(0.2) or b in blobs])
    if circles:
        img.drawCircle((circles[-1].x, circles[-1].y), circles[-1].radius(),SimpleCV.Color.BLUE,3)

if normaldisplay:
    img.show()
else:
    segmented.show()
```